# How do you set up the Cache-Control header using the Builder Pattern?

Tags: cache-control, okhttp

I tried to rewrite

```
request = request.newBuilder()
                 .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60)
                 .build();
```

as

```
CacheControl cacheControl = 
    new CacheControl.Builder()
        .maxAge(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .noCache()
        .build();

request.newBuilder()
       .cacheControl(cacheControl)
       .build();
```

but it is not equivalent since the `public` directive is not in the `Cache-Control` header.  How can i set this up with the `Builder Pattern`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not currently look like this is possible; see the [`CacheControl.java` source](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/CacheControl.java#L67) on GitHub.  You might file an issue requesting that that field be settable on the `Builder`.